# Where is the other half of my fourth degree Bézier curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, splines

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.2**

---

When I enter the following command, half of the fourth-degree spline is missing from the graph (i.e. it doesn't touch the last point). Is this a bug in *Mathematica* or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about Bézier curves?

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 4], Dashed, Green, 
 Line[pts]}, PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.5}, {-.5, 1.5}}, 
 Frame -> True], {{pts, {{0, 0}, {.5, 0}, {.5, .5}, {1, .5}, {1, 
 1}}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

Here's a screenshot of the output:
[image: missing part of fourth-degree Bézier curve]

What makes me suspicious is that the same behavior shows up in *Mathematica*'s own help file on `BezierCurve`.

[image: screenshot of mathematica's help files on BezierCurve]

Comment: This is probably a bug, cause on V10.1 on Win10 it shows the full curve as expected.

Comment: It seems to be a bug. This behavior does not occur in *Mathematica* 9.0.1 or 8.0.4 running on Windows. As such, it would be very helpful if you would state in the question your OS platform and the version of *Mathematica* you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I thought so, but didn't want to claim it was a bug without a second opinion. :) I have _Mathematica_ 10.0.0.0 running on Mac OS X x86.

Comment: I see the same on OS X with version 10.1 - in fact, the bug seems to persist for all degrees above the default 3. So I've added the bugs tag.

Comment: It works in V10.2 (Mac OSX).

Comment: In Linux I get whole curve in all *Mathematica* versions I have available: 8, 9, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, so it seems this bug is OS specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there is really something wrong with the `BezierCurve`, I made this work-around:

```
Clear[bezierCurve];

bezierCurve[pts_] := 
 First@ParametricPlot[
   BezierFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> Length[pts] - 1][t], {t, 0, 1}]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{bezierCurve[pts], Dashed, Green, Line[pts]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1.5}, {-.5, 1.5}}, 
  Frame -> True], {{pts, {{0, 0}, {.5, 0}, {.5, .5}, {1, .5}, {1, 
     1}}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

Since the spline degree is always one less than the length of the point list, I didn't adhere to the built-in syntax where the degree is specified separately through an option. I just let the function `bezierCurve` compute the appropriate degree automatically, to reduce the potential for error.

Comment: Thanks! I just ended up hard-coding it by looking up the formulas in wikipedia. Your approach is certainly more elegant. :)