# How to use BezierCurve or BSplineCurve to define a quarter of a circle?

Tags: graphics, splines

I know the command `Circle` can do that too, however, I want to be more flexible later on and want to know how to define this with the above mentioned functions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use something like this?  `Graphics[{Black, Thickness[.1], CapForm["Round"],  Circle[{0, 0}, ArmRadius + WireRadius, {0, -90 Degree}]}]` If you only want one end to be round, you can make two halves, one of which has `CapForm["Butt"]`.

Comment: This solution does not offer complex shaped designs... My example just serves as a guide. Being completly flexible seems to work only with `BezierCurve` or `BSplineCurve`(as I imagine). However, I completly failed trying any solution on that basis.

Comment: I think you'll have to explain what more complex shape designs you are looking for, otherwise the answer may end up  being too narrow for your purpose.

Comment: true, got the point! However, I think it would help, if I know, how to define a quarter of a circle by `BSplineCurve`. As far as I understood `BezierCurve` is just able to approximate a quarter of a circle. where `BSplineCurve`can treat that exact. Is that true?

Comment: Some info on how to construct a circle with rational splines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline#Example:_a_circle

Comment: @shrx - you beat me to it!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79785/2079

Comment: Also worth pointing out a bug that still exists in version 10.3: [Where is the other half of my fourth degree Bézier curve?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91146/245)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give a quarter of a circle,

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
  SplineWeights -> {1, Sqrt[2]/2, 1},
  SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}]
 ]
```

[image]

and this gives the whole circle,

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
    0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}},
  SplineWeights -> {1, Sqrt[2]/2, 1, Sqrt[2]/2, 1, Sqrt[2]/2, 1, 
    Sqrt[2]/2, 1},
  SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}]]
```

[image]

I got the info to make these from a combination of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline#Example:_a_circle) and [this page](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2000/AGraphHCI/SMEG/node5.html).  [This page](http://digbib.ubka.uni-karlsruhe.de/volltexte/documents/760493) looks very useful for digging into the theory behind it all.

Comment: I gave an expression for a general arc [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994).

Comment: hmmmm, would you say this is a duplicate of that question?

Comment: I'm on the fence regarding this.